# counting the number of values in an array with autofilled elements from rand function in c++

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program that generates random numbers within a given range and that is saved into an array in which I can count the number of the value in the array that is desired. The program that I made works fine without altering compilation error, however, I always get a 0 for the result of the count function, no matter the existence of the element that I'm counting for. Is there a way to fix this problem?

- This is the source code of random_function.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "random_function.hpp"


using namespace std;


Rand::Rand()
{
}


void Rand::Random_function()
{
    
    cout << "Enter amount of numbers to generate: ";
    cin >> range;
    if (range<=0)
    {
    cout <<"Error! Please enter the valid number and try again! "<<endl;
    }
    else {
    cout << "Enter minimum boundary: ";
    cin >> min;
    cout << "Enter maximum boundary: ";
    cin >> max;
    cout << "\n";
    
    if(max<=min || cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "\nError! Please enter the valid value and try again! " << endl;
    }
        
    else {
        
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
        
    for(int n=1 ; n <= range; n++)
    {

        cout << min + (rand() % static_cast<int>(max - min + 1)) <<endl;
    
    }
 }

                
        cout <<"\n"<< "Total random numbers generated: " << range<< endl;
   
    }
  }


void Rand::Count_function()
{
  
    extern int y;
    
    int array[range];
    int count=0;
    int random= min+rand() % static_cast<int>(max - min + 1);
    
//for some reason this for loop is not working. But there isn't any compilation error. 
    for (int i=0; i<range; i++)
    {
        array[i] = random;
        
        if(array[i]==y)
            count++;
        
    }
      //This part works fine, its just that for loop above doesn't 
    cout <<"The number of '"<<y<<"'s in the given list is: "<< count <<endl;

}
```

- This is a source code of the random function.hpp

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Rand
{
public:
    Rand();
    int range,min,max;
    void Random_function();
    void Count_function();
    
};
```

**This is main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include "random_function.hpp"

using namespace std;

int y;

int main()
{
    Rand call;
    call.Random_function();
    
    cout<<"Enter the value to count for: ";
    cin>>y;
   
    Rand call2;
    call2.Count_function();
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize your member variables in the constructor or modify them before calling `Count_function` so they could be 0 or anything else. Variable length arrays are also not standard C++ so your code is not portable.

Comment: `int random = min + rand()% static_cast<int>(max-min+1);` assigns a random number between min and max to the variable `random` and `for(int i = 0; i < range; i++) array[i] = random;` assigns the same value to the array[i] `range` times. Instead, you can write `for(int i = 0; i < range; i++) array[i] = min + rand()%static_cast<int>(max-min+1);`. And the values inputted for range, min, max are stored in object `call`, you are calling `Count_function` from object `call2` where the values are not initialized.

Comment: You can use the C++ `rancom_device`  and `uniform_int_distribution` to simply fill a `std::vector` with random numbers using `std::generate`. Also, keep your **interface** and **implementation** separate. Don't put the prompts and input in your `Random_function()`. Design an interface function to prompt the user for `count`, `max` and `min` and pass those values as parameters to your implementation of your `Random_function()`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).